# Including a runbook.ps1 script in your runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

Scenario:

I have 2 runbooks, runbook A and runbook B.

Inside runbook B, I want to load runbook A into memory.

Running below doesn't work, can someone help me out please?

```
.\runbookb.ps1
. ./runbookb.ps1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to *invoke* runbook B from runbook A, first of all please make sure runbook B exists in your Automation Account and is *published*. Then, depending on the runbook type, you need to use different syntax:

- For *PowerShell* runbooks, the correct syntax is: `./runbookb.ps1` or `. ./runbookb.ps1` (depending on whether you want the "dot-sourcing" behavior or not)
- For *PowerShell Workflow* runbooks, the correct syntax is: `runbookb`

If you really want to *load the runbook content into memory*, this is different:

- For *PowerShell* runbooks: `Get-Content ./runbookb.ps1`
- For *PowerShell Workflow* runbooks: use the Export-AzureRmAutomationRunbook cmdlet.

Comment: The Get-Content ./runbookb.ps1 doesn't work. It fails with the error "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Temp\pdur5g3d.hvp\runbookb.ps1' because it does not exist.". Am I missing something to be done before invoking the Get-Content cmdlet?

Comment: @AmoghNatu Here is one more caveat. In order for Automation to deploy the runbookb.ps1 file to this location, it needs to see that you are actually trying to invoke runbookb, or at least _pretend_ that you are trying to invoke it: `if ($false) { ./runbookb.ps1 }` `Get-Content ./runbookb.ps1`

Comment: That's awesome! I get the content now. But can you please explain to me what exactly happens when that if-condition is added? I mean, the control never enters that right? So just the presence of that line ./runbook.ps1 instructs azure automation to go and get the runbook into that location?

Comment: ALSO, which one would be better and why? :-) Because I see I can use both Get-Content as well as Export-AzureRmVMAutomationRunbook cmdlet to get the runbook.

Comment: Automation does not deploy all the runbooks as files by default. Instead, it tries to find runbooks that _might_ be invoked from the parent runbook, and deploys only those files to the sandbox executing the parent runbook. In order to determine the subset of potentially invoked runbook, Automation parses the PowerShell script searching for everything that looks like a script invocation. `Get-Content ./runbookb.ps1` does not look like a potential script invocation, but `if ($false) { ./runbook.ps1 }` does. This parsing is not intelligent enough to detect that this code branch will never run.

Comment: The AzureRmAutomation cmdlets require the runbook to authenticate to ARM first, which is not always convenient. However, if you need to authenticate for other reasons anyway, you can use those cmdlets as well. The advantage of Get-Content is that it is slightly more efficient. The obvious disadvantage is that the `if ($false)` thing looks a bit hackish.

Comment: One more difference: the Get-Content method will give you the runbook content at the moment of the parent job start, but the ARM cmdlets will retrieve the _current_ runbook definition. If you manage to edit the child runbook while the parent runbook is running, this may matter.

Comment: I see. I get it now. Thanks for the clear explanation Anatoli! Appreciate it.